# How to print image file in windows7 using command line LPR

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, printing, lpr

I have image file "test_image.png" and I ran this command on windows7 (64bit)

```
lpr -S <ipv4 address> -P "GodexG500" "test_image.png"
```

This command prints the image raw content which is not in base64 format. Let me know how would I do this so that actual image will print using above mentioned "LPR" command.

Comment: i thot you needed to use `-ol` [lowercase letter O, lowercase letter L] to print binary files with LPR.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: This doesn't work. I have tried this. Job is even not visible into print queue in windows. Let me know if there is any other option to print binary files using command prompt in windows

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, there is not any such thing _built into windows_. you will need to install an application to do that.

Comment: which application ?

Comment: a quick net search for `command line image print` brought up several mentions of `irfanview`. it seems to have a `/print` cli option = `/print="Name" -        print input image to specific printer and close IrfanView`. plus, this shows up = windows - command line tool for print picture? - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301101/command-line-tool-for-print-picture

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the way, and it works perfectly fine with windows machine
First we need to install inrfan_view application from here irfanview.com and then run this command in windows

> & 'C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe' .\test_image.png /print

(Note: Make sure when you print make print page setup in IrfanView application and choose "Stretch to page" or "Best fit to page" radio button as per your requirement)